# stack level too deep (SystemStackError) when loading hash via require

Tags: ruby, hash, hashtable, stack-overflow

I have a ruby script, containing only a hash table, that was written by another script by dumping it to a file using PP.pp(mediacontent,filehandle).

The script that generated this hash table did so by downloading data from a supplier page by page, parsing the XML, and converting the needed objects to this hash table that grows as the script downloads more data.

The dump looks like this, first 2 1/2 objects shown:

File: mediacontent.rb

```
# encoding: utf-8

$mediacontent =
{"099923045533"=>
  {"obj"=>
    {"external_id"=>"099923045533",
     "media_type_id"=>5,
     "active"=>true,
     "name"=>"F.D.B.",
     "duration"=>286,
     "published_at"=>"2013-05-29T20:05:11Z",
     "properties"=>
      {"host"=>"Vevo",
       "host_url"=> "http://example.com/sample.m3u8",
       "favorites"=>"0",
       "views"=>"8495",
       "trending"=>"298",
       "popular"=>"1401",
       "copyright"=>"2013 Hustle Gang/Grand Hustle/eOne Music",
       "src_img_path"=>"http://example.com/xyz.jpg",
       "src_img_dim"=>"1241x697"}},
   "data"=>{}},
 "AEA040800053"=>
  {"obj"=>
    {"external_id"=>"AEA040800053",
     "media_type_id"=>5,
     "active"=>true,
     "name"=>"Aadi",
     "duration"=>351,
     "published_at"=>"2009-10-02T00:00:00Z",
     "properties"=>
      {"host"=>"Vevo",
       "host_url"=>"http://example.com/sample2.m3u8",
       "favorites"=>"1",
       "views"=>"20160",
       "trending"=>"0",
       "popular"=>"0",
       "copyright"=>"EMI Music Arabia",
       "src_img_path"=>"http://example.com/sample2.jpg",
       "src_img_dim"=>"640x339"}},
   "data"=>{}},
 "AEAB20400094"=>
  {"obj"=>
    {"external_id"=>"AEAB20400094",
     "media_type_id"=>5,
      etc.
    },
   "data"=>{}},

   etc...
```

}

Pretty standard ruby hash that contains other hashes.

There are 75,000 primary keys in this list.

When I try to do the following:

```
ruby mediacontent.rb
```

or in a script

```
require "./mediacontent.rb"
```

I get the error

```
mediacontent.rb:0: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

The error goes away if I remove 30,000 entries or so from this table. I have verified that there's no endless nesting going on. Each primary key is a hash that contains the nested hashes "obj", "properties", and "data". That's it.

What I find strange is, the script that generated this table had no problem building this big hash table internally before dumping it out.  The script is supposed to read it back in (via require) if its execution gets interrupted and has to be re-run. This, too, was working just fine until the hash table grew to 75,000 items.

I'm running ruby 1.9.3p484. No Rails. Just Ruby.

Comment: [This](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002159) says that Array#hash returns a Fixnum, and [this](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Fixnum.html#M001079) tells you the size in bytes of a Fixnum in your platform.

Comment: @JustinWood - that second link doesn't go to any anchor on the page. If you're talking about the size property, it is impossible to invoke it if Ruby refuses even to load the hash.

It seems I have run into a maximum limit for the size of an object. The source file is about 52 megabytes. If I split it into 2 separate hash tables, they load just fine. If it's a size limitation, then the Ruby error message "stack level too deep" isn't quite the right message to display.

Comment: I this somethere you have very deep recursion, do you write the script yourself?

Comment: @majioa - I wrote the script myself, and there is no recursion whatsoever. The script is very basic: download an an XML file, parse it, save data objects in a hash table, repeat. Every 1000 objects, save the hash table to a separate Ruby source file. If the script is interrupted, it requires the source file containing the hash the next time it is run, and continues where it left off. This worked well until the hash table grew beyond a certain size. This appears to be a bug (or feature?) of Ruby that either limits the size of a hash table, or limits the size of a source file, not sure which.

Comment: ok, try to increase stack size twice with `ulimit`, for example to 16384 kbytes as: `ulimit -s 16384`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation, here's what I found:

- The problem isn't in the length of the Ruby source file that contains
  the hash table (currently over 50 MB).
- The problem is a limit that Ruby imposes on the size of a hash table in a source file. The hash table can be bigger if it's built while the script is running, but there's a limit to the allowed size when parsed from the source file.

This works just fine, to split the hash table into two, and put them into an array:

```
$mediacontent = []
$mediacontent << { (hash table of 37,500 items) }
$mediacontent << { (remaining 37,500 items ) }
```

Based on this, I must conclude that Ruby's error message is just wrong, or at least misleading. The problem isn't "stack level too deep". The error message should be more along the lines of "object too large".

Answer (score 0):

You could try increasing the size of the stack for your environment.

```
echo "ulimit -s 40000" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

and try again.

That assumes you are using bash, it might be .bash_profile, .profile, or whatever your particular shell uses, but you should get the basic idea.

If the stack size is different on the system generating this hash, this could explain why it doesn't incur the same problem.

Comment: the error appears in each environment I tried: Mac, Linux VM under Windows. Thanks for the tip though. I still think this is a flaw in the error message generated when Ruby parses a large object in a source file.